# Json Gallery conditional formatting not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I have a list with layout set to Gallery. The list has Title, URL and recently added a Display field. Currently clickable tiles are displayed and I now want these tiles to turn grey (disabled) when the list item column 'Display' is set to 1. (Prefer to use a boolean, but this didnt work either)
The tiles part work and so does hovering over. However I cannot manage to disable. Here is the code before I tried adding the disable condition:

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "width": "120",
  "height": "100",
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "href": "[$URL]",
      "target": "=if([$NewTab] == true, '_blank', '')"
    },
    "style": {
      "text-decoration": "none"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover ms-fontColor-gray150"
        },
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "min-width": "120px",
          "min-height": "100px",
          "margin-right": "10px",
          "margin-top": "10px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "center",
              "margin": "auto"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-row-title "
                },
                "style": {
                  "font-size": "12px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "[$Icon]",
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-su"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried changing the class attibutes to :

```
"attributes": {
  "class": "=if([$Display] == '1', 'ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt', '')"
},
```

But the styling disapears and conditional statement dooes not work. Any thoughts on the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you were setting the class, but if it was the `a` element then it was being covered by the children. Specifically, the first child `div` was setting it's own background color.

Changing your format to put your conditional in that first child `div`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "width": "120",
  "height": "100",
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "href": "=if([$Display],[$URL],'')",
      "target": "=if([$NewTab] == true, '_blank', '')"
    },
    "style": {
      "text-decoration": "none",
      "cursor": "=if([$Display],'pointer','default')"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "=if([$Display],'ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover ms-fontColor-gray150', 'ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary') + ' ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt'"
        },
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "min-width": "120px",
          "min-height": "100px",
          "margin-right": "10px",
          "margin-top": "10px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "center",
              "margin": "auto"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-row-title "
                },
                "style": {
                  "font-size": "12px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "iconName": "[$Icon]",
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-su"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The key portion being the expression used in the `class` property:

```
        "attributes": {
          "class": "=if([$Display],'ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover ms-fontColor-gray150', 'ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary') + ' ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt'"
        },
```

In the above, we are checking a Yes/No field with an internal name of `Display`. When it is true, we are setting the hover styles. When `Display` is false, we set it to use a different font color.

But, the link isn't actually disabled. So to keep it as close to your original format as possible we can add an expression to the `href` attribute:

```
      "href": "=if([$Display],[$URL],'')",
```

Unfortunately, hovering over disabled tiles will show a destination of `javascript:void(0);` which isn't a problem but it will still cause the item to have a pointer and seem clickable. So we need to set a conditional `cursor` style as well:

```
      "cursor": "=if([$Display],'pointer','default')"
```

This format looks something like this:

[image]

---

Typically, when I start seeing I'm having to use the same condition over and over again in multiple properties I like to refactor my formats so that I can have optional elements. In this case, I would make the `a` element optional. To do that you would need to make it a child of the `div` and use absolute positioning to cover the primary element with the `a` element. Then you can configure the `a` element without any conditions except for the `style:display` where you can set that to `none` when you'd like to remove it. This is absolutely not necessary in this case but it would likely make it easier to maintain.